# Recording video from browser and storing it for later view

Tags: flash, video, video-capture, opentok, tokbox

I am looking for solutions on recording and storing videos from browser using flash and playing it back for later use.

I have checked out the following:

**TokBox** (Archiving is not free)

I would like some suggestions to accomplish the following. It can be either open source or commercial (but with open source or free service preferred).

1. In a unique url, make users start recording the video using Flash and their webcam
2. Once recording is finished, the video must be stored on the server (preferrably Amazon S3)
3. Playback the video again for a particular user (no need to download the file)

Any suggestions to attain the goal?

Comment: I have used http://www.framey.com/ before. Its not free but it was a pretty good service.

Comment: @hackattack, Thanks for introducing me to framey.com. From what I see, it is a great service. Thanks again. Can you also provide me with other alternative services you had a look at? Finding such a similar service is totally tough and its a pretty unknown domain to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [RED5](http://www.red5.org/) server might be your best bet. It's like an opensource Flash Media Server and free, but requires for you to own a (JAVA capable) server. If I recall correctly the download also comes with a video recording and streaming example and there's a lot to find [on the net](https://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=red5+recording+video&oq=red5+recording+video&gs_l=hp.3..0i30j0i8i30l3.1097.3862.0.4100.22.16.1.5.5.0.145.1123.14j2.16.0...0.0...1c.jrg9sOj7Qdc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9e9d98b0df353a9e&biw=1118&bih=660).

Comment: If you want a free service to run a java server, check out [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). I use if for Django deployment, but it started with running Java/Scala services.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help you to record a video from browser using flash. And if you have any doubt just go through these URL's also , It might help you. Though i didn't work any video projects in Flash,i couldn't give you a clear solution.But i tried with my friends for you, I hope it might be usefull for you in any manner to find the right solution.

```
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/615/2/Getting-started-with-red5-server/Page2.html
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_can_I_record_web_cam_video_via_a_browser_-16540.html


var video:Video;
02  var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
03   
04      camera.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, active);
05      video = new Video();
06      video.attachCamera(camera);
07       
08  function active(event:Event):void
09  {
10      addChild(video);
11      camera.removeEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, active);
12  }
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution with server storing capabilities too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds Like you're wanting a Flash Media Server application.  With it you can record and store a users webcam on the server, then stream it back later.  You can add security to make sure that only logged in user are able to stream files.

While I'm not sure about Amazon S3 Storage, I know you can use Amazon's EC2 service pre-configured with the latest flash media server.   Cost is unknown. If you buy it for your own server, it ranges from free (for under 10 simultaneous users) to $4,000+ for full breadth of features.

If you download the free developer version, it's comes with A LOT of sample applications pre-built. Plus there are lots of tutorials online people here that can help with the code side of things, as it's a commercial product.    The latest version also can stream to iOS/HTML5

http://www.adobe.com/products/amazon-web-services.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately TokBox is neither open sourced nor "free" when archiving is concerned, but the good news is that their archiving functionality is in BETA and they are currently not charging any money for archiving (making it free for the time period). Unlike other products in beta, TokBox's archiving has been around for many months and it is just as polished as any paid product. You should try it out.

Each recording (archive) is recorded and stored on TokBox's servers as an archive Id. According to your specs, users start recording in a unique url. You will need your own database that maps your unique urls to TokBox's Archive IDs.

Since you'd want to store the video archive on your own servers, you can use TokBox's API to retrieve video download URLs and download the videos to your own server.

A year ago I played around with the archiving API and wrote a tutorial about it, hope you find it useful:
http://www.tokbox.com/blog/how-i-built-minute-grams-3-minute-tutorial/